# Android: Custom masking 2 bitmaps layered one above the other

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, draw, paint

easy now.

What I want eventually:

[image: a busy cat]

I want to have 2 bitmaps overlayed on a view. Same bitmaps with the one above have higher brightness than the below one.

Now when the user strokes(with touch event (like paint brush)) on the upper bitmap, I want those parts of the upper bitmap to go invisible.

For those who are familiar with adobe photoshop perhaps this will make more sense:
I want to draw a mask on an image being display so that only the unmasked parts remain visible. But the mask can be drawn from a brush with variable hardness/size.

How do I achieve this functionality? Direct me in in the line where I should research or give sample code.

Also, is it possible to draw strokes on an imageview with a brush which has variable hardness? I know that I can drawPath and drawArc on a canvas, but I do not know how to achieve the different brush strokes/styles.

Please pardon me if I haven't phrased my question right, or wasn't able to find similar duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FrameLayout to overlay one image over other in Android and for Custom Masking search FingerPaint on google.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but what about custom masking them with finger strokes etc?

Comment: It means to not mask an image in a regular pattern like rectangle or an oval. The user can drag his finger on the upper bitmap and make any part of it invisible, like the eraser tool in Microsoft Paint.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to do your own off-screen compositing, then render the composited image using an ImageView or perhaps a subclass with custom interaction. See [this sample code](https://github.com/ldo/porter_duff_browser_android) for an example of how to do such compositing using the Porter-Duff transfer modes.